# Why do I get bad sectors?

Tags: hard-drive

[image: bad sectors]

Why do I get bad sectors and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your hard drive is failing.**

Make a backup ASAP and buy a new hard drive.

Comment: This is 1 month old drive

Comment: @PurnenduNath - Then i's still under warranty. RMA it.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: If it is just a one-month-old drive, then that indicates that the quality of the drive is bad **or** it is a duplicate drive(i.e made from a random company and trying to imitate that their product is from one big company)

Comment: @PurnenduNath There should be some instructions on how to apply for warranty. if not dial the store asking for a replacement drive, but if the company who you bought it from has a way to do the similar thing, then go for it

Answer (score 1):

**First things first:**

### Back up what you can right now and get a new disk!

**Why?** Because your disk has got irreversibly damaged regions that are no longer writeable or even readable.

The OS usually marks such bad sectors and stops using them. However, once a disk starts to get them, it's likely that there will appear more damaged regions in the near future,

To get more information about your disk, you can check its SMART status and run some self-tests. You get there by selecting *"SMART data & self tests"* in the hamburger menu in the top right corner, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Note that many disks have *some* bad blocks. Even brand new disks can have bad blocks. How many depends on the threshold of the manufacturer (in this case it seems to be too many :) )

Comment: Yes, but those that are there "by default" should be blacklisted and remapped by the low level formatting or the disk's firmware and not by the OS or the file system, right? And I think those factory-marked bad sectors should not show up in this counter, do they?

Comment: Yes they do, but usually less then ten or twenty. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_sector and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T. The most interesting part is if the number increases. (but this is of course too many) Long time ago: http://askubuntu.com/a/473818/72216

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the SATA cable at first, it cause more bad sectors when it damage, there are also many reasons to find bad sectors, if Sata cable stopped the error the bad sectors will stop to back again , you maybe also need to change the power supply if it died not only the cable if it's a PC ,
after you change the Sata cable you can remove bad sectors forever using [Disk genius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) program , making the hard disk as a slave on a running device, or you can use [Hiren's BootCD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) after you burn it on a CD or make boot able USB on a flash memory.

Note:

1-The bad sectors often will cause not responding and system failure, remove it will cause damage for the nearest files for it so some files will not work again.

2- before you remove the sectors backup your important files to another disk.

3- After remove it by Disk Genius you will need to repair Ubuntu using fsck /dev/sda2 command by a live CD or in the black screen if it appear command port option , while sda2 is the system partition at you maybe will other number, any way only system can be fix by this command, for Microsoft operation system you maybe need to install a new one but try system repair option first.

**Note:** If the hard has physical damage new bad sectors will appear again on the running area, so you will need to get another healthy hard disk.

Comment: Does "disk genius" run on Ubuntu?

Comment: No , I tried to run it using Wine HQ but it didn't work, so the best way to run it is by using Hiren's BootCD, or if you have a device working by Microsoft operation system you can connect the infected hard as a slave and run Disk Genius direct to fix the hard disk, the last Version of Hiren's BootCD has the last Disk Genius version till now so you will not need to download it , and anyway it's size about 50 megabytes and you can find portable version.

Comment: Anyway to try to fix any bad sectors you will need to run a live CD to can write on system partition , and the Hiren's Boot CD is a live CD that running now using windows 10 MS OS , so you can run the program using it, just burn it on  CD or boot able on flash memory as I said above.